# MOV to variable pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, i386

I declared word at 0x7c02:

```
ramSpace: dw 0x500
```

Is it possible to directly change the memory at the address of which ramSpace points? Currently to change the memory at 0x500 I have to either:

```
MOV BX, [ramSpace]
MOV [BX], BYTE 01
```

or:

```
MOV [0x500], BYTE 01
```

However typing:

```
MOV [ramSpace], BYTE 01
```

changes the 0x7c02 value to 01 from 0x500. Is there a way to point to 0x500 from variable in memory? Something like this:

```
MOV [[ramSpace]], BYTE 01
```

Comment: No that's not possible unfortunately. PS: `0x7c00` hints that you are writing a boot sector in which case you should have code at that address and not data.

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake. I have JMP on 7c00 and dw on 7c02. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, x86 doesn't have any instruction which would load a word from memory and use it as an address to access another word/byte of memory. You have to use an intermediate register to do this.